return firts present Optional
I have a few validation cases which returns Optional.empty() or Optional.of(new Object())
How to return the first non empty result of this cases?
on this method I want to return the first not empty case result
public Optional<Object> validate(Objects tmp) {
        Optional<Object> result = case1(tmp);

        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            result = case2(tmp);
        }
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            result = case3(tmp);
        }
        return result;
    }

case example
private Optional<Object> case1(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
        } else {
            return Optional.of(new Object());
        }
    }


Use or to chain these Optionals together. Wrap each subsequent call in a lambda, because or expects a Supplier.
public Optional<Object> validate(Objects tmp) {
    return case1(tmp)
        .or(() -> case2(tmp))
        .or(() -> case3(tmp));
}

